# Copy a docker ARG into an Angularjs config file

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, environment-variables, dockerfile, runtime

I have a simple AngularJS application that is built through a Jenkins pipeline and a Docker file.  When running the Jenkins job, the environment is set.  Then it builds to one of two environments: dev or integration.  What I need is a way to get that variable into the angular app.

The docker file uses the environment  to build different config settings like:

```
    ARG env
    COPY build_config/${env} /opt/some/path...
```

I need to get that env into one of the controllers.  Is there a way to copy env into a controller.  I attempted something like the following:

```
    COPY ${env} path/to/angular/file/controller
```

I have searched and tried different methods but cannot find a solution to work for the Jenkins with Docker pipeline.

Comment: `ARG` is used to create a variable, in your case the variable name is `env`. The variable will hold some string value. Suppose that `env` has the string value `dev`. Is your goal to copy the **string** `dev` to `path/to/angular/file/controller`, or to copy the **file/directory** `dev` to `path/to/angular/file/controller`?

Comment: @ShaneBishop The goal is to copy the string dev into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `RUN` to write a string to a file:

```
RUN echo "$env" > path/to/angular/file/controller
```

If you want to append to the file instead of overwritting it, use

```
RUN echo "$env" >> path/to/angular/file/controller
```

Comment: How would I access the string now in the file?

Comment: You could `cat` the file to get the file contents: `cat path/to/angular/file/controller`

Comment: Is there a way to assign the contents of that file to variable?  Something like ```var baseUrl = ${env} + "/rest/of/the/url"```?

Comment: If you want to assign the contents of that file to a variable in a shell script, you can use `my_var="$(cat path/to/angular/file/controller)"`

Comment: It is not in a shell script.  I need to assign the contents of the file to a variable in the angularjs code itself.

Comment: Have you tried googling it? https://www.google.com/search?query=typescript%20how%20to%20read%20a%20file

Comment: Yes, I have been researching it.  I haven't figured it out yet which is why I brought it to stack overflow.